# Do something for first user visit and till the time the visit ends in rails

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies, session-cookies

I have a rails application in which I show a notification on each page and it is shown only when the user visits my application for the first time. For this I use cookies.

application_controller.rb

```
before_action :first_time_visit, unless: -> {cookies[:first_visit]}
def first_time_visit
 cookies.permanent[:first_visit] = 1
 @first_visit = true
end
```

I use @first_visit variable in my application.html.erb file to detect if this is a first time visit of the user. The problem is if the user keeps browsing to different pages(in the first visit), the notification is gone because it is no more a "first_visit". I want to show the notification till the time the "first time visitor" is browsing my application. Only after the user closes the browser and comes back, this notification should not come again (Its no more a first_visit nor an ongoing session of user browsing).

How do I do this in rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the following code worked for me.

```
if cookies[:first_visit] != "1"
    cookies.permanent[:first_visit] = 1
    cookies[:first_session] = 1
    @first_visit = true
  else
    if !cookies[:first_session].blank?
      @first_visit = true
    else
      @first_visit = false
    end
end
```

Basically, the key is, in the first ever visit, I am creating a permanent cookie. So, this will remain even after I close my browser and other than that I am maintaining a cookie named as "first_session" which is a temporary cookie and gets destroyed as soon as browser is closed. So, till the time, the first session of first visit is going on, "first_session" cookie is available and thus I am able to show my notification. 
On the other hand, When the user closes the broser, and comes back at some later time, cookie named "first_visit" is already "1" and thus no notification is shown to the user.

Hope this helps someone looking for a similar usecase!